# Getting a Value from row and column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a table with 30-minute time increments on the y-axis and the day on the x-axis. How could I write a formula to display the value at a given increment and day?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: normaly x and y axes refer to graphs, no? but I get what you mean (I think) - see below. hope it helps. ta

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot(s)/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hKlo9-XG3oGni1j0ew?e=LqBa9c) refer:

```
=INDEX(Table2,MATCH(C5,Table2[values],0),MATCH(day_,Table2[#Headers],0))
```

[image: Index formula - sample]

---

Named ranges - your reference:

[image: named ranges / cell references]